# Duplicate Key Error on MongoDB Model, Even When Model is Not Enforcing Uniqueness for that Value

Tags: mongodb

In my app I have an endpoint that allows a user to create a new document by simply passing something like this:

```
{ name: { long: "some name" } }
```

Now, the relevant portion of the model for this document looks like this:

```
name: {
  long: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  short: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  }
}
```

As you can see, I don't have "short" set to "unique: true". However, the user is getting this error:

```
 "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: hr.agencies index: name.short_1 dup key: { : null }"
```

So, clearly the problem here is that once you have more than one "name.short" with a value of `null`, its producing a dupe error. However, since I don't have `unique` set to `true` in the model, I'm not sure why it's enforcing this as a rule.

What could the issue be here, and how can I resolve it? Is there a way I can explicitly say, don't enforce uniqueness on this field?

Comment: Try to remove index from the `short` key then see what happens

Comment: How does one remove the index from the key?

Comment: `db.collection.dropIndex({ "name.short": 1  })`

Comment: Perfect. That worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the index from the `short` key using

```
db.collection.dropIndex({ "name.short": 1 })
```